# Why is my origin upside down?

Tags: animation, armature, origin

I'm trying to animate this character, but, somewhere, along the way, the origin for its armature got flipped upside down and I'm not sure why. I thought it might have something to do why the roll value (that's why I included it). Not only is it jarring but it's also making it harder to move the character along the x and y axis. I'm not sure what's going on and I hope someone is able to identify the problem based on the pictures below. The top one is in object mode and the one below is in edit mode

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure that the origin is aligned the way you want when your armature is on Rest pose, also in the Transform Orientations panel, choose Local or Global, not Normal?

Comment: Okay I'll try that. By rest pose do you mean like the way it is in edit mode?

Comment: yes, that's it, but maybe share your file?